# Does batching queue (tf.train.batch) not preserve order?

Tags: tensorflow

I've set up a filename-producing queue using `tf.train.string_input_producer` with the `shuffle` option set to `False`, coupled to a batching queue using `tf.train.batch` (i.e. non-shuffling). Looking at the list of examples being read, while the ordering is *almost* perfectly preserved, it is not strictly so. For example the first few sample are 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 10, ..., where the number corresponds to the position of the sample within the first file read. After that the ordering is almost prefect for several hundred samples, but it occasionally switches adjacent samples. Is this expected behavior? Is there some way to enforce that the ordering is preserved, so that one does not have to keep track of what file got read when, etc?

I should say that I conditionally discard some samples by enqueuing either 0 or 1 sample at a time, and setting `enqueue_many` to `True` in the batching queue. None of the samples above are being skipped however and so this shouldn't in principle be an issue.

Comment: It is not expected. Are you using more than one thread for tf.batch? That would give random order. Another non-determinism issue (doesn't seem to be the case here since no elements are missing) --  Supervisor + summary statistics can also add non-determinism by consuming elements of your queue at some intervals

Comment: I do have multiple threads running so that may explain it. Setting to one thread does seem to eliminate the behavior, but it's not perfectly reproducible and so it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Yaroslav has mentioned in the comments, a single thread would do the trick. In addition to a single thread, you should set num_epochs = 1. If you don't, it will keep producing batches and it may seem like order is not preserved as it loops from the start again. I hope this works.

Having said that though, I hope someone can come up with a better answer to solving this!

Comment: Thanks for this answer it really helped me a lot. I'm new in tensorflow, could you please clarify the `num_epochs = 1`, is that the number of examples per epoch, or the number of epochs to be processed...?

Comment: @Cinn number of epochs to be processed.